# Between date range check in the column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a Column where i Need a Formula or Macro to check & say there article already in between the same date range. Below the example table.

```
Article No. Start Date  End Date    Result
1           10/12/2018  11/12/2018  Repeated
2           10/20/2018  11/18/2018  Unique
3           10/18/2018  11/19/2018  Unique
4           10/25/2018  11/28/2018  Unique
1           10/13/2018  11/11/2018  Repeated
```

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). At the Moment your question is too broad and does not include any or enough sample code. You probably will not get help because people around here do not like person's who try to free ride on their knowledge. Show some effort by asking a good questions and answers will follow. Currently it is unclear if you seek to get a formula or if it should be VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I think below code is what you're looking for:

```
=IF(A6=$A$2,IF(AND(AND(B6>=$B$2,B6<=$C$2),AND(C6>=$B$2,C6<=$C$2)),"Repeated","Unique"),"Unique")
```

Here's the application:
[image: Sample]

*Note that you should compare a single cell (A2) with other cells to find unique/repeated values.*

Comment: Good One, but the i have data where in keeps on appending, the above data is just a example, i have a data with 10K rows..

Comment: Unfortunately Excel doesn't support something like `FOR` looping technique to check all article numbers in your worksheet. You need to check this statement in VBA Loop (FOR...NEXT)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible with a `COUNTIFS` formula, that counts if …

- Article number is the same
- AND *Start Date* is greater
- AND *End Date* is smaller

that count is greater than `1` if it is a within another date range. So you can catch that with a simple `=IF`. Try the following:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,B:B,"<=" & B:B,C:C,">=" & C:C)>1,"within another range", "unique")
```

Note that this marks only the entry that is within the date range of another date range of the same article. But it doesn't mark the first one.

So the result would be:

```
Article No. Start Date  End Date    Result
1           10/12/2018  11/12/2018  Unique                  'this is the outer range.
2           10/20/2018  11/18/2018  Unique
3           10/18/2018  11/19/2018  Unique
4           10/25/2018  11/28/2018  Unique
1           10/13/2018  11/11/2018  within another range    'only inner range gets marked.
```

It doesn't recognize over lappings like

```
1           10/13/2018  11/14/2018  Unique    'over lappings are considered as unique
```